# How to open a new component in Angular on a click in the <td> tag which contains user name?

Tags: html, angular

I want to open a new component when I click on the `<td>` tag present in my HTML file:

I have a dashboard.component.html and in that, I have a table which consists of name, ID, address etc.

Now when I click on the `<td>{{item.name}}</td>` I should be able to navigate to a new component lets say for eg. detials.component

below is my dashboard.component.html code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of collection.data | paginate: config">
        <th scope="row">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [attr.id]="item.id">
            <label class="custom-control-label" [attr.for]="item.id"></label>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>{{item.name}}

        </td>
        <td>{{item.enquiryNo}}</td>
```

My dashboard.component.ts file is like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { faChevronDown, faSearch, faChevronLeft, faChevronRight } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'smart360-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  faChevronDown = faChevronDown;
  faChevronLeft = faChevronLeft;
  faChevronRight = faChevronRight;
  faSearch = faSearch;
  collection = { count: 60, data: [] };
  config = {
    id: 'custom',
    itemsPerPage: 10,
    currentPage: 1,
    totalItems: this.collection.count
  };

  public maxSize: number = 7;
  public directionLinks: boolean = true;
  public autoHide: boolean = false;
  public responsive: boolean = true;
  public labels: any = {
    previousLabel: '<--',
    nextLabel: '-->',
    screenReaderPaginationLabel: 'Pagination',
    screenReaderPageLabel: 'page',
    screenReaderCurrentLabel: `You're on page`
  };



  constructor() {
    //Create dummy data
    for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.count; i++) {
      this.collection.data.push(
        {
          id: i + 1,
          name: "Name" + (i + 1),
          enquiryNo: "0019924" + i,
          status: ['danger', 'success', 'warning'].sort((a, b) => .5 - Math.random())[0],
          mobileNo: "+91 9849163057",
          area: "Old Alwal",
          source: "Branch",
          raisedOn: new Date()

        }
      );
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onPageChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.config.currentPage = event;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a path for that component Detail, then in the dashboard component constructor inject Router and declare an onCLicRenderDetail method to render it to the detail component and execute this method on the onCLick of the html element

dashboard.component.ts

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {}

renderDetail(detailId: number) {
  route.navigateByUrl('rotuePath/' + datailId);
}
```

```html
<td (click)="renderDetail(item.id)">{{item.name}}</td>
```

Comment: I shall try and revert back asap